# Basic react select onChange not firing

Tags: reactjs, events

This seems to have been asked a lot but after trying every solution in the similar questions I can't find an answer.

I'm learning react and have a very simple app for practice. The select element in the SelectTime component is not triggering its onChange event when the selection is changed:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            date: new Date().addHours(0),
            location: "London/GMT",
            offset: 0,
            secondsSinceStart: new Date().getSeconds()
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerId = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerId);
    }

    tick() {
        const secs = this.state.secondsSinceStart + 1;
        this.setState({
            date: new Date().addHours(this.state.offset), secondsSinceStart: secs
        })
    }

    setOffset(newOffset) {
        console.log("Change!");
        this.setState({offset: newOffset})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ClockFace date={this.state.date} secondsSinceStart={this.state.secondsSinceStart}/>
                <h1>In {this.state.location} it is <FormattedDate date={this.state.date}/></h1>
                <SelectTime setOffset={this.setOffset} offset={this.state.offset}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function FormattedDate(props) {
    return <span>{`0${props.date.getHours()}`.slice(-2)}:{`0${props.date.getMinutes()}`.slice(-2)}:{`0${props.date.getSeconds()}`.slice(-2)}</span>
}

class ClockFace extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const rotationCount = {
            hours: parseInt(this.props.secondsSinceStart / 60 / 60 / 24 / 2),
            minutes: parseInt(this.props.secondsSinceStart / 60 / 60),
            seconds: parseInt(this.props.secondsSinceStart / 60)
        };

        return (
            <div className={"clockCircle"}>
                <ClockHand type={"hours"}
                           rotation={(((rotationCount.hours + (this.props.date.getHours() % 12) / 12)) * 360) + "deg"}/>
                <ClockHand type={"minutes"}
                           rotation={(rotationCount.minutes * 360) + (this.props.date.getMinutes() * 6) + "deg"}/>
                <ClockHand type={"seconds"}
                           rotation={(rotationCount.seconds * 360) + (this.props.date.getSeconds() * 6) + "deg"}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function ClockHand(props) {
    return <div className={"clockHand " + props.type} style={{transform: `rotate(${props.rotation})`}}/>
}

class SelectTime extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(event) { //this never fires
        console.log("Change!");
        console.log(event.target.value);
        // this.setState({value: e.target.value});
        // //this.setState({value: e.target.value});
        // this.props.setOffset(parseInt(e.target.value))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <label>Timezone
                    <select onChange={this.onChange}>
                    <option value="0">London/GMT</option>
                    <option value="1">Paris/ECT</option>
                    <option value="-6">New York/EST</option>
                </select>
            </label>)
    }
}


export default App;

Date.prototype.addHours = function (h) {
    this.setTime(this.getTime() + (h * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    return this;
};
```

I've tried adding .bind(this) and arrow functions to the onChange event as per the other times this has been asked.

What am I missing?

Comment: It works fine. What is the problem?

Here is the URL:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fvzpem?file=src/App.js

Comment: Yeah I'm the same, it works for me.

Comment: I think it's something in my local environment then, it works on the stackblitz link but not locally. I've never used NPM, node, babel or webpack before either so don't have a clue where the issue might be